# How to create a URL for Azure File Share with SAS

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk, azure-file-share

I already know how to create a download link using SAS to create a downloadable link for a Blob in Azure as per the docs. Using this code:

```
sas = generate_blob_sas(
  account_name="account",
  container_name="container",
  blob_name="myblob",
  account_key="accountKey",
  permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
  expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)
blob_url = f'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/a?{sas}'
```

However is this possible for File shares too? I want to create the `sas` but for a File Share

Update:

I was able to do it from the Azure Storage Explorer, by right clicking on the file and clicking "Get Shared Access Signature".

I also then tried to use the code:

```
sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name="acc",
    account_key="key",
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(service=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do that. However, you would need to use `azure-storage-file-share` package instead of blob.

The methods you are looking for are [`generate_share_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare?view=azure-python#azure-storage-fileshare-generate-share-sas) for generating SAS URL for a File Share or [`generate_file_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare?view=azure-python#azure-storage-fileshare-generate-file-sas) for generating SAS URL for a file inside a File Share.

You can learn more about this SDK here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=python.